# Symfony2 multiple bundles with same configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entities

I have one bundle, `WebDificilBundle` which is fully working, now, I want to make a second bundle named `WebUserBundle`, I want to make this bundle to be some kind of "between" for multiple bundles, so I need entities from `WebUserBundle` to be exactly the same, and by the same I don't mean the sctructure, I mean to use the entities from other bundles (this example `WebDificilBundle`)

How can I make this work? Just copying entities folder from one to another?

Comment: How about inheritance?

Comment: Just use the entities from one bundle in the other?

Answer (score 0):

Option A - Use the same entities. It doesn't make any sense to copy the same entities into the second bundle. Just use them. Add the line YourProject/WebDificilBundle/Entity/yourentity.php in the controllers/services/whatever of WebUserBundle and use them normally.

Option B - I suppose you want to make as independent as possible both bundles, to be able to reuse them separetly in other projects. In that case, you can copy the entities in WebUserBundle.